# Convert Python files to executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyinstaller, py2exe

Python: 3.6.5

PyInstaller: 3.4

I have problems to convert my project into a executable using PyInstaller, Py2Exe and Auto-Py-To-Exe.
I wanna have just one file. I need my assets folder in my exe. 
The command which was generated by Auto Py To Exe is:

```
pyinstaller -y -F -w -i "D:/Eigene Dateien/Documents/Coding/Python/hangman/icon.ico" --add-data "D:/Eigene Dateien/Documents/Coding/Python/hangman/assets/images";"images/" --add-data "D:/Eigene Dateien/Documents/Coding/Python/hangman/assets/sounds";"sounds/" --add-data "D:/Eigene Dateien/Documents/Coding/Python/hangman/assets/words.txt";"." "D:/Eigene Dateien/Documents/Coding/Python/hangman/main.py"
```

If I use this in PowerShell it says:

```
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:175
+ ... nts/Coding/Python/hangman/assets/images";"images/" --add-data "D:/Eig ...
+                                                          ~~~~~~~~
Unerwartetes Token "add-data" in Ausdruck oder Anweisung.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:262
+ ... nts/Coding/Python/hangman/assets/sounds";"sounds/" --add-data "D:/Eig ...
+                                                          ~~~~~~~~
Unerwartetes Token "add-data" in Ausdruck oder Anweisung.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:344
+ ... ds.txt";"." "D:/Eigene Dateien/Documents/Coding/Python/hangman/main.p ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unerwartetes Token ""D:/Eigene Dateien/Documents/Coding/Python/hangman/main.py"" in Ausdruck oder Anweisung.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:163
+ ... eien/Documents/Coding/Python/hangman/assets/images";"images/" --add-d ...
+                                                         ~~~~~~~~~
Der Operator "--" kann nur für Variablen oder Eigenschaften verwendet werden.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:250
+ ... eien/Documents/Coding/Python/hangman/assets/sounds";"sounds/" --add-d ...
+                                                         ~~~~~~~~~
Der Operator "--" kann nur für Variablen oder Eigenschaften verwendet werden.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Sorry, some text is German :/

```
D:\Eigene Dateien\Documents\Coding\Python\hangman>pyinstaller -y -F -w -i "D:/Eigene Dateien/Documents/Coding/Python/hangman/icon.ico" --add-data "D:/Eigene Dateien/Documents/Coding/Python/hangman/assets/images";"images/" --add-data "D:/Eigene Dateien/Documents/Coding
/Python/hangman/assets/sounds";"sounds/" --add-data "D:/Eigene Dateien/Documents/Coding/Python/hangman/assets/words.txt";"." "D:/Eigene Dateien/Documents/Coding/Python/hangman/main.py"
75 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4
75 INFO: Python: 3.6.5
76 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
77 INFO: wrote D:\Eigene Dateien\Documents\Coding\Python\hangman\main.spec
80 INFO: UPX is not available.
82 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['D:\\Eigene Dateien\\Documents\\Coding\\Python\\hangman',
 'D:\\Eigene Dateien\\Documents\\Coding\\Python\\hangman']
82 INFO: checking Analysis
146 INFO: Appending 'datas' from .spec
151 INFO: checking PYZ
187 INFO: checking PKG
189 INFO: Building because toc changed
189 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
410 WARNING: One binary added with two internal names.
410 WARNING: ('libGLESv2.dll',
 'C:\\users\\meiss\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'BINARY')
410 WARNING: was placed previously at
411 WARNING: ('PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'C:\\users\\meiss\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'BINARY')
13466 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
13476 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\meiss\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit\runw.exe
13476 INFO: checking EXE
13478 INFO: Building because console changed
13478 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
13483 INFO: SRCPATH [('D:\\Eigene Dateien\\Documents\\Coding\\Python\\hangman\\icon.ico', None)]
13483 INFO: Updating icons from ['D:\\Eigene Dateien\\Documents\\Coding\\Python\\hangman\\icon.ico'] to C:\Users\meiss\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpiwaatz96
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\meiss\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\meiss\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\meiss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\meiss\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\meiss\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\meiss\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 838, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\meiss\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 784, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 32, in <module>
  File "c:\users\meiss\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 433, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\meiss\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\meiss\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 522, in assemble
    icon.CopyIcons(tmpnm, self.icon)
  File "c:\users\meiss\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\icon.py", line 177, in CopyIcons
    return CopyIcons_FromIco(dstpath, [srcpath])
  File "c:\users\meiss\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\icon.py", line 134, in CopyIcons_FromIco
    for i, f in enumerate(icons):
  File "c:\users\meiss\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\icon.py", line 104, in __init__
    entry.fromfile(file)
  File "c:\users\meiss\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\icon.py", line 65, in fromfile
    self._fields_ = list(struct.unpack(self._format_, data))
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 16 bytes
```

This is the output in IntelliJ (english)

Comment: Can you run it in english?

Comment: I dont think pyinstaller has an add-data command ... edit the specfile that is generated to add to `a.datas` , and you can use Tree to walk and include entire directories as opposed to individual files

Comment: Have you tried executing the command in Command Prompt (cmd.exe) instead of Powershell?

Comment: @alec935 edit the post (ran in IntelliJ because I didn't know how to run in english)

Comment: @JoranBeasley According to the [PyInstaller documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/spec-files.html#adding-data-files) `--add-data` is a valid argument.

Comment: @Xukrao In cmd with administration rights it doesn't generate an exe. :/

Comment: @MelanX Then what is the exact error message when executing from cmd?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/6nszUNTs @Xukrao

Comment: it looks like your icon in maybe not sized correctly or is not the correct format? ... try leaving the icon bit out

Comment: @JoranBeasley yeah I tried without the icon but still not working

Comment: try using `python -m pyinstaller ...` ? maybe try and edit the spec file directly? if you want to post a zip i could try and see ... but i suspect there is some mismatch between what version of pyinstaller and what version of python

Comment: @JoranBeasley it says "No module named pyinstaller" D: and i edited the spec file.. maybe I should add versions of Python (3.6.5) and PyInstaller (3.4).. but a zip file.. yeah, why not.. i try to send it just to you (dm)

Comment: @JoranBeasley http://www.mediafire.com/file/hw0wqcp6ckgqpe9/ (private messages not possible :D)

Comment: download not available

Comment: @JoranBeasley Okay.. this time I checked the Link https://www.mediafire.com/file/d6ozqei4oo6dpdz/

Answer (score 0):

I have had some luck by downgrading Pyinstaller to version 3.1. `pip install pyinstaller==3.1`